# How are getState and dispatch imported in redux-thunk action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import jsonPlaceholder from '../apis/jsonPlaceholder';

export const fetchPostsAndUsers = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  await dispatch(fetchPosts());

  _.chain(getState().posts)
    .map('userId')
    .uniq()
    .forEach(id => dispatch(fetchUser(id)))
    .value();
};

export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');

  dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data });
};
```

In the above code getState and dispatch functions are passed as arguments to the action creator function, what i m puzzled about is why are these functions not imported from anywhere or does react/redux somehow import them for us?

Comment: these are arguments to the function. The function will be invoked by passing them. Nothing needs to be imported in this case

Comment: ok i feel i asked a stupid question now, here is possibly another one, if these functions are passed as arguments where do they come from  they would still need to exist in the current module for them to be passed as arguments right, or does react pass them from somewhere else?

Comment: Why would they need to exist in the current module to be passed as arguments? That would dramatically reduce the utility of functions generally. You *export* those functions, so they can be used elsewhere (presumably wired into the redux store somewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I will try to clear your confusion, 
As you know action creators returns plain javascript object, but thunk is a middleware which allows you to return function instead of plain javascript object from the action creators, so when you use thunk if you return **plain javascript** object from action creator its handled in normal way, but when you return a **function** from action creator than thunk handle it and call this function with **dispatch** and **getState**, so you can dispatch an action asynchronously, you are not passing these arguments, see it this way that you are returning a **callback** from action creator and thunk call this callback with these arguments.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect a react component with redux using a connect function provided by redux you will pass in to functions: mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. Those will be the parameters your looking for (dispatch and getState).

Answer (score 0):

Thunk is a function which optionally takes some parameters and returns another function, it takes dispatch and getState functions, and both of these are supplied by Redux Thunk middleware